# Bootstrapping standard normal data does not produce a mean of zero and standard deviation of 1

Tags: r

Please let me know my mistake. I expected bootstrapping a standard normal data produces a mean of zero and standard deviation of 1, but my example does not.
    rm(list=ls())

Create random data with a mean of zero and standard deviation of one

```
V1 <- rnorm(9, mean=0, sd=1); V2 <- rnorm(9, mean=0, sd=1); V3 <- rnorm(9, mean=0, sd=1)
V4 <- rnorm(9, mean=0, sd=1); V5 <- rnorm(9, mean=0, sd=1); V6 <- rnorm(9, mean=0, sd=1)
V7 <- rnorm(9, mean=0, sd=1); V8 <- rnorm(9, mean=0, sd=1)

charDataDiff <- as.data.frame(cbind(V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7,V8));charDataDiff
```

rename the columns

```
colnames(charDataDiff) <- c("s380","s390","s400","s410","s420","s430","s440","s450"); charDataDiff

patchId      <- c("C", "B", "A", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"); patchId
```

provide an ordering variable

```
idColor      <- c("C", "B", "A")
```

Put all the pieces together to create the data

```
charDataDiff <- cbind.data.frame(patchId,charDataDiff); charDataDiff
```

Split the data by patchId

```
patchSpectrumBiasSplit <- split(charDataDiff, charDataDiff$patchId)
```

Order the data by idColor

```
patchSpectrumBiasOrdered <- patchSpectrumBiasSplit[idColor]
```

Remove the first column

```
patchSpectrumBias <- lapply(patchSpectrumBiasOrdered, "[", 2:9)
```

Bootstrap

```
sampleOne   <- function(x) x[sample(seq_len(nrow(x)), replace = TRUE), ]
sampleBoot  <- function(x, n) replicate(n, sampleOne(x), simplify = FALSE)
applyMedian <- function(l) do.call(rbind, lapply(l, apply, 2, median))
k <- lapply(lapply(patchSpectrumBias, sampleBoot, n = 1000), applyMedian)
```

Calculate the mean, I expected the mean to be zero following the law of large numbers.

```
bootMeansBias <- do.call(rbind, lapply(k, apply, 2, mean));bootMeansBias
```

Calculate the standard deviation, I expected the standard deviation to be one

```
standardError <- do.call(rbind, lapply(k, apply, 2, sd));standardError
```

Comment: Crossposted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532997/bootstrapping-standard-normal-data-does-not-produce-a-mean-of-zero-and-standard

Comment: @Matt The cross-post now has been closed and at least one statistically interesting answer has been offered here, so this looks like the right place for this thread to remain.  Thanks for flagging it!

Answer (score 5):

You could never expect the mean to be exactly 0 if you were using the law of large numbers.  You're not using large numbers in your sample, only your bootstrap.  Your bootstrap will build up a representation out of the sample.  You're just highlighting a problem in bootstrapping, that the results you get depend on the sample.  So, a sample of 9 is very unlikely to have a mean of 0 and can deviate quite a bit from it.  A sample of 3 is even worse.  Bootstrapping won't fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank all, I modified my code and realized my mistake. the new code is as follows:

```
rm(list=ls())
n <-2000
```

Create random data with a mean of zero and standard deviation of one

```
a <- lapply(1:8, function(x)cbind(rnorm(n)))
b <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind,a ))
```

rename the columns

```
names(b) <- c("s380","s390","s400","s410","s420","s430","s440","s450")
```

Create a second random data

```
c <- lapply(1:8, function(x)cbind(rnorm(n)))
```

rename the columns

```
d <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, c))

names(d) <- c("s380","s390","s400","s410","s420","s430","s440","s450"); str(d)
```

Create a list of the above data

```
e <- list(b,d)
```

Bootstrap

```
sampleOne   <- function(x) x[sample(seq_len(nrow(x)), replace = TRUE), ]
sampleBoot  <- function(x, nn) replicate(n, sampleOne(x), simplify = FALSE)
applyMean <- function(l) do.call(rbind, lapply(l, apply, 2, mean))
k <- lapply(lapply(e, sampleBoot, nn = 100), applyMean)
```

calculate the mean, it is almost zero

```
bootMeansBias <- round(do.call(rbind, lapply(k, apply, 2, mean)),3); bootMeansBias
```

calculate the standard deviation, it is almost 1

```
standardError <- round(do.call(rbind, lapply(k, apply, 2, sd)),3);standardError
standardDeviation <- standardError*sqrt(n); standardDeviation
```

Thank you all

Ragy Isaac